# Python--read files, save the file names and access to these files

Tags: python

I build

```
totalset = {}
```

and extract the file names from folders A, B, C, D by

```
for file_name in (os.listdir(full_subdir_name)):
    full_file_name = os.path.join(full_subdir_name, file_name)
```

Now I want to build something called namelist that contains all the file names, and I could traverse all the files in the folders through:

```
for file in namelist[A]:
    blabla...

for file in namelist[B]:
    blabla.. .
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use a "list comprehension".  Here is an example of how you could do it:

```
lst_names = [os.path.join(full_subdir_name, n) for n in os.listdir(full_subdir_name)]
```

So then you would build the full `namelist` something like this.  First you should set up a list of names.

```
# example using Windwows filenames
# note that we use "raw strings" with r'' so the backslash will not be weird
lst_names = [r'C:\Users\steveha\Desktop', r'C:\Users\steveha\Documents', r'C:\Users\steveha\Music']

# example using Mac or Linux filenames
lst_names = ['/home/steveha/Desktop', '/home/steveha/Documents', '/home/steveha/Music'
```

Once you have `lst_names` set up with your names, build the full `namelist`:

```
namelist = {}

for full_subdir_name in lst_names:
    namelist[full_subdir_name] = [os.path.join(full_subdir_name, n) for n in os.listdir(full_subdir_name)]
```

Personally I think it would be easier to read with a shorter variable name than `full_subdir_name`:

```
namelist = {}

for f in lst_names:
    namelist[f] = [os.path.join(f, n) for n in os.listdir(f)]
```

Comment: So how should I traverse lst_name?

Comment: I added some examples of setting up `lst_name`.  Does this make it clear?

Comment: If you don't know the list of names ahead of time, and you want to scan the file system, you might want to use `os.path.walk()`.